# Difference in context this and getContext()

Tags: android, this, android-context

What is difference between `this` and `getContext()`, when I say `this` I mean `this` within an `Activity`.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

In general there are two type of classes. Ones that extend [`ContextWrapper`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html) class (`Activity`, `Service`, `Application`) and those that do not extend it (like `View`).

1. If class extends `ContextWrapper` then you can use `this` as `Context`. Such classes normally do not have `getContext()` method.
2. Those classes that do not extend `ContextWrapper` but still save and use `Context` normally expose `getContext()` function. And you cannot use `this` as `Context` in such cases.

And these two cases are mutually exclusive. At least I don't recall classes that extend `ContextWrapper` and have `getContext` at the same time.

Comment: Actually, the important type is `Context`, not `ContextWrapper` (which is a subclass of `Context`). So, for instance, a `MockContext` can also use `this` where a `Context` is required, even though `MockContext` does not extend `ContextWrapper`.

Comment: What about getBaseContext()?

Answer (score 16):

`getContext()` is not defined in an Activity. It's used in a `View` (or `View` subclass) to get a reference to the enclosing context (an Activity).

Answer (score 5):

There is no difference. When you are in an Activity, getContext() will return this. This is because an Activity is a context!

Comment: Than when is a difference between this and getContext() is there a difference when we use Service (maybe brodcast receiver...) ,I mean is there any place where this will not suffice and there will be need for getContext() ?

Comment: In a View, `getContext()` returns the containing activity.