# Cannot make a static reference error

Tags: java, android, ontouchlistener, touch-event, ontouch

So i will just post the code that is giving the error if anyone has any idea as to why this doesn't work let me know, with an explanation. (do not just say that this is a bad way to code or something) (or at least if you do explain yourself). So the code below is supposed to switch to another screen when a color that someone has clicked is true!

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
   int x = (int) event.getX();
   int y = (int) event.getY();
   if(isInsideCircle(x, y) ==  true){
      //Do your things here
       if(redColor == lastColor){
// error is here   Intent i = new Intent(this, YouFailed.class);
// and here        Activity.startActivity(i);
       } else {
           addPoints++;
       }
   }else {

   }
   return true;
}
```

There are two errors:

The constructor `Intent(DrawingView, Class<YouFailed>)` is undefined

and

***Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method startActivity(Intent) from the type Activity***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `v` for accessing `startActivity` method instead of trying to call `non-static` method in `static` way:

```
Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), YouFailed.class);
v.getContext().startActivity(i);
```

Comment: how would i find out more about the v or its method getContext(); ?
and not from the java api i cant find it there

Comment: @devin: `v` is object of `View` class  and `getContext()` method is define in `View` class which return `Context` by which you can access `startActivity` method. find more detail here [View.getContext ()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getContext%28%29)

Comment: yes i relized that after i typed it. its actually the argument that is passed in that method thank you though

Answer (score 0):

It seems that error is here,

```
   Intent i = new Intent(this, YouFailed.class);
```

because  in `Intent` constructor your first parameter is `DrawingView`,instead it should be

> The Intent action, such as ACTION_VIEW.

So Change this to

```
   Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), YouFailed.class);
```

Comment: how would i find out more about v or its method getContext(); ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6229052/difference-in-context-this-and-getcontext

Answer (score 0):

Try to use your activity context instead inline class context :

```
Intent i = new Intent(YourActivity.this, YouFailed.class);
YourActivity.startActivity(i);
```